# ROLLUP not working on a column that has mathematical operation of two aggregated values

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a simplified code below:

```
SELECT
(
    t1.name,
    t1.shortName,
    (
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN condition1 THEN t1.qty
            WHEN condition2 THEN t1.qty * t1.multiplier 
        END)
    -
    SUM(
        (SELECT (
            CASE WHEN condition1 THEN t2.qty
                WHEN condition2 THEN t2.qty * t2.multiplier 
            END) AS count
        FROM table t2))
    ) AS variance
FROM table t1
GROUP BY t1.name, t1.shortName WITH ROLLUP
```

On above code, the variance shows the correct amount on each row except for the total/subtotal rows.
Upon googling, it turns out that WITH ROLLUP only works on columns that are aggregated so the above doesn't work because the value of variance is more like constant since the SUM is inside it...

So I tried to rewrite the code into this:

```
SELECT
(
    t1.name,
    t1.shortName,
    SUM(
    
        CASE WHEN condition1 THEN t1.qty
            WHEN condition2 THEN t1.qty * t1.multiplier 
        END
    -
    
        (SELECT (
            CASE WHEN condition1 THEN t2.qty
                WHEN condition2 THEN t2.qty * t2.multiplier 
            END) AS count
        FROM table t2)
     ) AS variance
FROM table t1
GROUP BY t1.name, t1.shortName WITH ROLLUP
```

And it's not working.... Basically what I want to do is aggregate values in table1 and table2, then perform mathematical operation between them, display the result in a column, then do ROLLUP...

Comment: `t2` is not defined in your query, so it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually the `CASE` expression, not the arithmetic.  One work-around is to calculate the unaggregated values in a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.shortName,
       SUM(t1_cond) - SUM(t2_cond) AS variance
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             (CASE WHEN condition1 THEN t1.qty
                   WHEN condition2 THEN t1.qty * t1.multiplier 
              END) as t1_cond,
             (CASE WHEN condition1 THEN t2.qty
                   WHEN condition2 THEN t2.qty * t2.multiplier 
              END) as t2_cond2
      FROM t1
     ) t1
GROUP BY t1.name, t1.shortName WITH ROLLUP;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa58928e4878643797a48a571facedfd) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that this method does calculate the variance (albeit on a working query).